# How to correctly format the tabularx with a varying column width and centerized text

Tags: tabularx

I am facing the problem to format my `tabularx` in a proper way. The tables should have the following format with centerized text:

[image: wanted]

My code for that:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{First Number (that is a longer text)} & \textbf{Second number (indeed also a long text)}\\
        \hline \\[-0.5ex]
        This is a long text with no sense but that might contain a linebreak & 3 & 3\\[1.5ex]
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{mytable}
\end{table}
```

So I have been trying around a little bit, but it turns out that formatting is harder for me than I thought earlier. When centering the text the `tabularx` seems to have no floating column width. How do I do that?

The closest I got to that was the folling code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|X|X}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{First Number (that is a longer text)} & \textbf{Second number (indeed also a long text)}\\
        \hline \\[-0.5ex]
        This is a long text with no sense but that might contain a linebreak & 3 & 3\\[1.5ex]
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{mytable - v2}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|X|X}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{First Number (that is a longer text)} & \textbf{Second number (indeed also a long text)}\\
        \hline \\[-0.5ex]
        This is a long text with no sense but that might contain a linebreak & 3 & 3\\[1.5ex]
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{mytable - v3}
\end{table}
```

which turns out as:

[image]

Comment: The text in each cell should be centred vertically or horizontally?

Comment: I suppose it would look best if it was centred vertically and horizontally

Comment: For column heads, yes (usually). For long texts in cells, this is debatable.

Comment: Lets say we want it horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ tabularx, caption, float}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.75\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.75\hsize}X}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{First Number (that is a longer text)} & \textbf{Second number (indeed also a long text)} \\
        \hline
        This is a long text with no sense but that might contain one or several linebreaks & 3 & 3 %\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{mytable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]